# How to get boolean value from a JSONfield in Django?

Tags: python, django

When entering data in a `JSONField` from the Django admin it's not allowed to enter boolean, only string or float or integers. So how should I enter a boolean value so it can be retrieve later one ?

```
obj.params = {"fast": 3, "slow": 6, "shift": "True", "signal": 2}
obj.save()

> obj.params['shift']
'True'
```

I could do :

```
params = {k: True if v == 'True' else v for k, v in obj.params.items()}
params = {k: False if v == 'False' else v for k, v in obj.params.items()}
```

But isn't a simpler way to store and fetch booleans from a `JSONfield` ?

Answer (score 1):

Using json.loads will probably be correct in your case!

```
import json

obj = {"fast": 3, "slow": 6, "shift": "True", "signal": 2}

# Accessing the JSON-encoded string
shift_value_str = obj['shift']

# Converting the string to a boolean value
shift_value_bool = json.loads(shift_value_str.lower())  # Convert to lowercase before loading as JSON

# Now shift_value_bool will contain the boolean value
print(shift_value_bool)
```

Comment: I've tried your solution but it says `TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not dict. 
`

Comment: does "shift" is not alway return "True" or "False" ??

Comment: Before using json.loads to check you can check "shift" is dict or not, if not dict => using json.loads

Answer (score 0):

You could store a 1 (True) or a 0 (False) as your dict values. And then check & compare later on.

```
>>> 1 == True
True
>>> 0 == False
True
>>> 0 == True
False
```

Example + expected output:

```
obj.params = {"fast": 3, "slow": 6, "shift": 1, "signal": 2}
obj.save()

obj.params['shift'] == True
>True
```

Answer (score 0):

To automatically convert the boolean value stored in a JSONField to an actual boolean in Django, you can use Django's built-in JSONField's `loads()` method. This will deserialize the JSON-encoded string and automatically convert the boolean values to the appropriate Python boolean type.

data = json.loads(obj.js)
shift_value = data['shift']

By using `json.loads()`, the value of `obj.js` (which is initially a JSON-formatted string) is parsed into a Python dictionary. The boolean value `'True'` is then automatically converted to the boolean type `True`.

Comment: Any idea why it says `TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not dict
` when I call `json.loads` with my string `obj.js` ?

Comment: From what I understand Django convert JSON string into a dictionary, and then it's not possible to `json.load` the dictionary. I did the test again by inserting a verified JSON string into the JSONField, and when I query the object it returns an object of type `dict`